# Can i get the events from events database dynamically(in code)?

Tags: java, android, database, calendar, android-intent

I am developing a calendar application.
And i have a need to list all the events store in calendar to list in my layout.
So that i need to fetch all the events from the calendar database.
How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's calendars, and then get its events, take a look at [android calendar's EventLoader class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/calendar/EventLoader.java) and related classes.

The content provider for calendar events is accessible using this URLs:

for SDK version < 8 : `content://calendar/events`

for SDK version >= 8 : `content://com.android.calendar/events`

Comment: Thats ok and i agree. But i need to retrieve the events from the phone database. That is getting the all the events.

Comment: I can not see any difference between all events and the events from the phone database, could you give description a little bit more?

Comment: ya you are right. I said all the events in phone as events in phone database.